# Is there any way to prevent two or more windows of the same program from merging into one in the Launcher on the left edge of the screen?

Tags: unity, launcher

Lets say if I have 2 or 3 Firefox windows open. I dont want them to merge into a single icon as it does and shows 3 arrows on the left side of the icon. Instead i want it to show 3 different icons. the reason i want this is to make navigation between windows easier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that if you click the icon, *2x when its not the active application*, that you'll then see the windows of that application spread across the desktop?

When spread across the desktop like this, you'll see a thumbnail view of the windows, and you're then able to click on the appropriate thumbnail to bring it to the foreground. This behavior makes for clear+easy navigation instead of guessing which icon belongs to which window.